# Перевод систем счисления int в int из 2 в 16 -ричную

Tags: c++, qt

```
QString str_mat = "01011010";
 qDebug() << "str_mat: " << str_mat;
int str_mit = str_mat.toInt(nullptr,2);
qDebug() << "str_mit: " << str_mit; // в десятичку всё ок
if(str_mat.toInt(nullptr,16) == 0x5A) // ошибка !!! число мракобесное if (16846864 == 0x5A)
    qDebug () << "мы тут";
  qDebug() << "--------- "  ;

QString sdaf = "11111111";
qDebug() << "sdaf: "<< sdaf;
int zzz = sdaf.toInt(nullptr,2); // из двойки в десятичку 
qDebug() << "zzz: "<<zzz; 

 QString ass;
 ass.setNum(zzz);
 qDebug() << "ass: " << ass;
 int i_ass = ass.toInt(nullptr,2); // в случае 16-рички переведет 255 как 597
 qDebug() << "i_ass: "<< i_ass;

Вывод :
str_mat:  "01011010"
str_mit:  90
--------- 
sdaf:  "11111111"
zzz:  255
ass:  "255"
i_ass:  0
```

А как из десятички в 16-ричку ??

Comment: `if(str_mat.toInt(nullptr,16) == 0x5A)` вы тут пытаетесь перевести из 16 ричной системы строку str_mat = "01011010", т.е. в 16 ричной системе счисления число 01011010 это совсем другое число что в двоичной

Comment: Существует много алгоритмов, есть два способа. 1)делить на 16 и остаток от деления превращать в цифру. 2) Учитывая что байт содержит всегда две цифры HiLo, то `Hi=(bt >> 4)` а `Lo=(bt & 15)`. Ну и... можно просто воспользоваться библиотечными ф-циями.

Comment: Мне кажется вы немножко не поняли как работает `toInt`. В пример `255 превратится в 597` всё правильно - 0x255 это 597. То есть toInt берёт строку, и пытается её интерпретировать как запись в некоторой системе счисления, то есть для строки 255 при интерпретировании как 16-ричной системы получим 597, а как 8-ричной - 173

Comment: я прекрасно понимаю о чём вы говорите, но я не знаю как это исправить, какой код мне написать ???

Comment: @timob256 Вам ниже в ответе рассказали про `QString::number` и даже примеры привели в комментарии. Это то что вам нужно.

Comment: @vegorov спасибо уже справился :3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы нигде не переводите в десятичную систему.

```
int a = 10;
```

здесь 10 хоть и записано в десятичной системе, но компилятор сам его приведет в удобную ему систему (в нашем случае это скорее всего двоичная).

```
int x = 0x10;
```

а здесь записано шестнадцатеричное число, но все равно, в x будет записано в машинноудобном формате.

Поэтому, гда Вы пишете

```
int str_mit = str_mat.toInt(nullptr,2);
```

то переводите не в десятичную, а с двоичной в удобную компилятору/процессору систему (а то, что она двоичная, какая разница. Вполне могла быть и троичной или любой другой).

А с этой формы можно перевести в любую другую удобную для отображения, например 16-ричную

```
QString s = QString::number(str_mit, 16);
```

Заметьте, переводим в строку - так как строка может хранить "отображение".

Но если это сложно понять, тогда вот упрощенный код

```
QString n2m(QString origin, int from, int to)
{
    int temp = origin.toInt(nullptr, from);
    return QString::number(temp, to);
}
```

и соответственно  10->16

```
QDebug() << n2m("100", 10, 16);
```

Comment: в общем с двоичной в десятичную я справился, а как с десятичной в шестнадцатеричную у вы не знаю

Comment: Спасибо добавил код `qDebug() << "str_mit: " << str_mit;` после этой строки вставляем 
    `QString s = QString::number(str_mit, 16);`
    `if(s.toInt(nullptr,16) == 0x5A)`  и видем вывод : `мы тут`  :3